# Function to add class to <form> element?

Tags: sidebar, forms

I'm using the Sidebar Login script by Mike Jolley, I would like to add a class of "clearfix" to the  element tag. I have been unable to find a solution to this so far.

I'd also like to understand any solution given, so if you would like to briefly explain how the function works I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Add a link to the plugin’s source code.

Comment: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/sidebar-login/trunk/includes/class-sidebar-login-widget.php - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin does not create a `<form>` tag itself. It uses [`wp_login_form`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L257) to do that, and that function [does not provide a way to add a class to the `<form>` tag](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L276). You can see that by looking at the `widget` method, which is what generates the front end content.

I don't see a way to do what you want to do, but there is an action before the form-- `do_action( 'sidebar_login_widget_start' );`-- and one after-- `do_action( 'sidebar_login_widget_end' );`-- that would let you wrap the whole form in some other markup.

However, I very much doubt that you need to add a class to that tag. I would bet that you can do anything you need by writing CSS rules using the existing markup.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for that explanation, I understand now :)

And I have just realised how to accomplish what I need - apply the properties of clearfix to form instead of trying to add a class to it.. I do feel silly.

I really do appreciate you taking the time to explain this to me.